# I shorted my Arduino Uno from 5V to GND and now i think both pins are dead

Tags: arduino, short-circuit, arduino-uno

So basically I shorted my Arduino Uno and I think the 5V pins and GND pins are dead (yes those are the ones I shorted)

I was playing around and I did a really stupid thing, what I did is I got 2 MF wires and plugged them into 5V and GND and then connected it to an LED, as soon as I did I heard a spark and by reflex I snapped back causing the cables to snap off (thank god) the short lasted for a split-second and I smelt (smelled idk) something weird and I just ignored it, I then played around some more and also tried to test the 5V and GND by making a basic fade LED with a breadboard (and a resistor) and it didnt light up, I then plugged in the output pin and it still didnt light, though I think it is because those wires thats at the very last and bottom etc that I didn't connect. Can someone tell me if I killed those pins and also I know that I didn't fry the arduino because the red leds (yes red because mine didn't turn green before and after short) and I'm still scared because I'm fitting a motor shield that uses 5v and gnd (every arduino circuit uses 5v and gnd) and it might not work (along with other circuits)

Comment: Nobody here can tell you for sure what happened but from what you have described, you may well have bricked your Uno.

Comment: Look for blown capacitor, voltage regulator or fuse. You probably broke something.

Comment: What are "MF wires" and what was the other end connected to?

Comment: Maybe you blew a trace off the board or possibly killed the regulator if the board was being supplied from a higher voltage. It's possible that it's easily repairable. If a ground trace was blown off it might not be as good a situation.

Comment: @Gil I assume OP means Male-Female, though that was not the first interpretation that came to mind.

Comment: Is your uno a genuine one, or a clone? Do you have a schematic for it?
In a similar situation (with a WeMos D1 mini board) I was lucky, because only the shottky diode on the board have fried from overcurrent. If your board had such a device, you might be lucky too.
AFAIK, the regulatos on genuine UNO boards have short-circuit protection, so they _should_ be ok.

Comment: 1) What power supply were you using for the Arduino Uno? Do you have any way of testing that that is still working? 2) Does anything look burnt or discoloured on the Arduino? - you might have to use a magnifying glass to inspect it properly.

Comment: @Gil it's male-female

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nothing looks blown nor discoloured, it is a clone I'm sure of it, I used to have a genuine until it melted (I wont get into it) and it had green LEDs now only has Red btw I don't think it **MELTED** because It'd like explode but it more just survived the meltdown

Comment: @KaremAssar Depending on how much money you are able to invest in your hobby, you need a multimeter (something like an Aneng 8008) and the knowledge of how to use a multimeter, such as don't short-circuit a power supply - there are plenty of videos available on the Internet showing how. A low-cost "bench PSU" with short-circuit protection and a variable current limit would be a good idea. Those two items might save you money in the long term if you have a tendency to blow up components ;)

Comment: I did something without regard for safety, I paid the price, my arduino uno is not bricked nor burned, I just wanted to be relaxed without work and forget the resistors and just plug it in directly. Resistors are there for you not to blow up your house along with your local starbucks

Comment: @KaremAssar Don't worry about the colour of an LED unless the documentation says that the colour means something. If it is on then it means that it has electricity flowing through it.

Comment: Magic smoke and wrecked stuff is the price of doing home-brew electronic projects.  It's why we don't play with AC mains :)